# NetBeans 8.2 - Shortcut to view background processes

Tags: netbeans, netbeans-8

Is there a keyboard shortcut or menu item that will display the running background processes?

My situation is: all of my "lower bar" space is taken up by tabs for other functionalities. Now the IDE has started indexing the maven repositories but is not showing the background process "tab" in the "lower bar" area, so I can't cancel it.